# How to resize a data template containing a rectangle?

Tags: wpf, canvas, datatemplate, itemscontrol

The main idea is that i want to draw some rectangles on a canvas using the mouse events (mouse down/move/up) and put them into a collection. After checking a checkbox, the rectangles template is changed and they can be moved or resized.

I looked into a previous project posted on codeProject  [Code Project](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/wpf/wpfdiagramdesigner_part1.aspx). The code is working for me if i create the objects from XAML, not by code.

This is how the XAML looks so far:

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbMoveResize" Content="Move and resize" Grid.Row="0"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cbDrawRectangle" Content="Draw rectangle" Grid.Row="0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" Grid.Column="0"  Background="Gray"   Width="Auto" Height="Auto" MouseMove="Image_MouseMove" MouseDown="Image_MouseDown" MouseUp="Image_MouseUp" MouseLeave="leaveGrid" MouseWheel="UIElement_OnMouseWheel">
                <Image x:Name="bmpImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                <Canvas IsHitTestVisible="True" x:Name="imageCanvas" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=bmpImage}"  Height="{Binding Height, ElementName=bmpImage}">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding rectTest, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MainWindow}}}">

                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <Canvas  IsItemsHost="True"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path = r.X}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path = r.Y}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentControl Height="{Binding r.Height, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="{Binding r.Width, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="nume">
                                    <ContentControl.Style>
                                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource defaultTemplate}"/>
                                            <Style.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cbMoveResize, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource moveAndResizeTemplate}"/>
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                            </Style.Triggers>
                                        </Style>
                                    </ContentControl.Style>

                                    <Rectangle Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="2" Height="{Binding r.Height, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="{Binding r.Width, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </Canvas>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Grid Name="smallGrid" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Name="btnLoad" Margin="2" Height="25" Content="Load" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnLoad_Click"/>

            <Canvas x:Name="grid2" Grid.Row="1"  Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=smallGrid}"  Height="Auto">
                <Image x:Name="cropIm" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=grid2, Mode=OneWay}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=grid2, Mode=OneWay}" />
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Move class:

```
public class Move : Thumb
{
    public Move()
    {
        DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(Move_DragDelta);
    }
    MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
    private void Move_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Control designerItem = DataContext as Control;
        var xx = designerItem;
        if (designerItem != null)
        {
            double left = Canvas.GetLeft(designerItem);
            double top = Canvas.GetTop(designerItem);

            Point rectPos = designerItem.TransformToAncestor(Application.Current.MainWindow).Transform(new Point(0, 0));

            Canvas.SetLeft(designerItem, rectPos.X + e.HorizontalChange);
            Canvas.SetTop(designerItem, rectPos.Y + e.VerticalChange);
        }
    }
}
```

Resize class:

```
class Resize : Thumb
{
    public Resize()
    {
        DragDelta += new DragDeltaEventHandler(Resize_DragDelta);
    }

    private void Resize_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        Control designerItem = DataContext as Control;

        if (designerItem != null)
        {
            double deltaVertical, deltaHorizontal;

            switch (VerticalAlignment)
            {
                case VerticalAlignment.Bottom:
                    deltaVertical = Math.Min(-e.VerticalChange, designerItem.ActualHeight - designerItem.MinHeight);
                    designerItem.Height -= deltaVertical;
                    break;
                case VerticalAlignment.Top:
                    deltaVertical = Math.Min(e.VerticalChange, designerItem.ActualHeight - designerItem.MinHeight);
                    Canvas.SetTop(designerItem, Canvas.GetTop(designerItem) + deltaVertical);
                    designerItem.Height -= deltaVertical;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            switch (HorizontalAlignment)
            {
                case HorizontalAlignment.Left:
                    deltaHorizontal = Math.Min(e.HorizontalChange, designerItem.ActualWidth - designerItem.MinWidth);
                    Canvas.SetLeft(designerItem, Canvas.GetLeft(designerItem) + deltaHorizontal);
                    designerItem.Width -= deltaHorizontal;
                    break;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                    deltaHorizontal = Math.Min(-e.HorizontalChange, designerItem.ActualWidth - designerItem.MinWidth);
                    designerItem.Width -= deltaHorizontal;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Right now, if I check the Move and resize checkbox, every rectangle is movable and gets an additional border for resize, but when I try to change its size, it only changes the size of the content control, and the rectangle move within it.